# Any 2-dimensional algebra over a field is isomorphic to one of the given form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

This is an exercise from section 1.5 Pierce's *Associative Algebras*: Let $F$ be a field of characteristic not equal to 2. Part a says to show that every $F$-algebra with $F$-space structure $A=x_1 F\oplus x_2 F$ is isomorphic to an $F$-algebra such that $\lambda_{x_1}=id_A$ and $\lambda_{x_2}$ acts by $\lambda_{x_2}(x_1)=x_2$ and $\lambda_{x_2}(x_2)=ax_1$ (where $\lambda_s$ is left multiplication by $s$).

Firstly, I'm not familiar with the term "$F$-space". I am going to assume that is a different word for "$F$-vector space". It's not hard to show that if $e=\alpha x_1+\beta x_2$ is the unit in $A$, I can perform a change of basis on $A$ that takes $x_1$ to $e$ and $x_2$ to any vector not in the span of $e$, but I have no idea how to do this in such a way that preserves the multiplication on $A$.

Edit: I realize that taking $x_1$ to $e$ won't work since I need to map the unit to the unit. I'm now more confused than before about how change of bases work for algebras over a field; If I take $e$ to be a basis element, then how can I do a change of basis on $A$ to any basis that does not contain the unit e?

Comment: Yu can write down an isomorphism of $2$-dimensional algebras in this case. Start with a linear map $f$, which is determined by the values on the basis $(x_1,x_2)$. Write $f(x_1)=f_1x_1+f_2x_2$ etc. Then use that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ and $\det(f)\neq 0$ to determine solutions $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$ from the equations.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a $2$-dimensional $F$-algebra. Then as you observe, there exists a unit $1\in A$ and one can take $\alpha\in A$ linearly independent from it. Then $\alpha^2\in A$ so it can be written as $\alpha^2=a\alpha+b$ for $a,b\in F$. By replacing $\alpha$ with $\alpha-a/2$ (since $F$ does not have characteristic $2$), you can assume $a=0$. Then $x_1=1$, $x_2=\alpha$ is your desired basis.

Comment: "By replacing $\alpha$ with $\alpha -a/2$ ... " -- Yup, the old completing the square. If only high school students knew how often that comes up even in higher mathematics  ...